# Dragging image onto webpage and showing a preview immediately while uploading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to create an online editor and the user can 1) drag an image from his disk and drop it onto the page. 2) The page then shows a preview of the image while the image is being uploaded (fake ajax by iframe or something, this I can do) in the background.

What are the optimal/recommended solutions to do 1) and 2)? Also consider I'm already using jQuery in other parts of my app.

Comment: upload can be done with ajax and FormData (or fake iframe in < HTML5). But drag&drop isn't possible in < HTML5 without flash, java, ... . I don't know about the preview...

Comment: It's possible to drag an image onto a page. I'm sure even in non HTML5 browsers. It's not so new.

Comment: I think I found something https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/